# Turn pandas dataframe list into boolean column

Tags: python, pandas

I have run into some unexpected error while try .isin()
Here's the problem. I've scrapped web, turned into dataframe. Now I'd like to make changes to make the data more usable for the project. 
From scrapped data, one column contains all the features, it's a list in json, but in pd, it's a "**non-null object**":

```
"feature": ["Wi-Fi", "LAN", "LED"]
```

I'd like to create new Boolean column base on each feature, which will be helpful down the road. 
It should look like this

```
Product    Wifi    LAN   LED
1          True    True  True
2          True    False False
```

I've tried both **str.contains** and **.isin()**, but only got errors. 
Such as

```
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

What is a better way to tackle this problem?

Also, the original data is in Japanese, I've loaded dataframe with **"encoding="utf-8"** How to best coding when with utf8 in pandas? I'm using notepad++ as editor.

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible sample of input data set? What is `feature` - is it a JSON __string__ or a list of features?

Comment: please press [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43914655/edit) and put data set sample to your question - it's hardly readable as a comment

Comment: `{"name": "CHEZ MADU ", "address": "5-17-62", "access": "30", "tel": "042-465-3533", "hour": "9:00〜22:00", "offday": "-", "web": "http://www.hakka-group.co.jp/shoplist/", "feature": ["Wi-Fi", "LAN", "Non-smoking"]},`
this is one line of raw data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `apply` with `in` if need check value in `list`:

```
df = pd.read_json('sample.json', lines=True, encoding="utf-8")
print (df)
   access  address                     feature        hour        name offday  \
0      30  5-17-62  [Wi-Fi, LAN1, Non-smoking]  9:00〜22:00  CHEZ MADU       -   
1      30  5-17-62  [Wi-Fi, LAN2, Non-smoking]  9:00〜22:00  CHEZ MADU       -   
2      30  5-17-62  [Wi-Fi, LAN3, Non-smoking]  9:00〜22:00  CHEZ MADU       -   

            tel                                     web  
0  042-465-3533  http://www.hakka-group.co.jp/shoplist/  
1  042-465-3533  http://www.hakka-group.co.jp/shoplist/  
2  042-465-3533  http://www.hakka-group.co.jp/shoplist/  

mask = df['feature'].apply(lambda x: 'LAN1' in x)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: feature, dtype: bool
```

Comment: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'`
Got this from json.loads.
`df = pd.read_json('test.json', encoding="utf-8")` could this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Ok, what is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'col']))` of your problematic column?

Comment: `<class 'list'>`

Comment: Ok, so maybe need check some item in list by `mask = df['col'].apply(lambda x: 'LAN' in x)`

Comment: it's working! and I use df['LAN'] = mask to add it as a new column. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think `df['LAN'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: 'LAN' in x) `, but it is same.